# Maven child module failing to find parent pom/artifact within image built with Docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

The project structure is like

```
parent-project
-- pom.xml
-- child-project-1
    -- pom.xml
    -- Dockerfile
-- child-project-2
    -- pom.xml
```

When mvn test is run in child-project-1 locally it works fine. However, when mvn test is run within the Docker image of child-project-1 it is not finding the parent pom.

I tried adding parent pom.xml using ADD/COPY in Dockerfile but it is throwing out of build context error. Wondering how to reference the parent pom from the maven module for which we are building Docker image

Below is the log, **as mentioned earlier there is no issue with child-project-1 pom.xml and it is building fine when built outside Docker**.

```
+ docker-compose -f ./child-project-1/src/test/resources/config/docker-compose.yml build test
Building test
Step 1/5 : FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8
 ---> 080cf1fccf1c
Step 2/5 : COPY . /usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af309a791cce
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9fa9a23570f
Step 4/5 : RUN chmod +x /usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1/src/test/resources/config/run-tests.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3263333ba5a4
Step 5/5 : CMD /usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1/src/test/resources/config/run-tests.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 32d391ba99a3
Successfully built 32d391ba99a3
Successfully tagged config_test:latest
+ docker-compose -f ./child-project-1/src/test/resources/config/docker-compose.yml up test
Creating config_component_1 ... 

[36mtest_1            |[0m ------------ End Environment ------------
[36mtest_1            |[0m /usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1
[36mtest_1            |[0m [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[36mtest_1            |[0m [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[36mtest_1            |[0m [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.parent:child-project-1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.parent:cdx-components-test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10
[36mtest_1            |[0m  @ 
[36mtest_1            |[0m [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[36mtest_1            |[0m [ERROR]   
[36mtest_1            |[0m [ERROR]   The project com.parent:child-project-1:[unknown-version] (/usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1/pom.xml) has 1 error
[36mtest_1            |[0m [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.parent:child-project-1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.parent:cdx-components-test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10 -> [Help 2]

test_1            | [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
test_1            | [ERROR]   
test_1            | [ERROR]   The project com.parent:child-project-1:[unknown-version] (/usr/src/parent-project/child-project-1/pom.xml) has 1 error
test_1            | [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.parent:child-project-1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.parent:cdx-components-test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```